# Restangular: add prefix to id on all requests

Tags: restangular

In my api, I need to specify the id as "id:" + some id, eg /suppliers/id:1234
Is there a way to add this globally so that I can do `Restangular.all('someresource').get('1234')` as usual in my services (instead of doing `Restangular.all('someresource').get('id:' + resourceID)` kind of stuff  for each one)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `addFullRequestInterceptor`
https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addfullrequestinterceptor